# Set the value of an input element in a django form

Tags: django-forms

I have a `ModifyUserForm` as follows:

```
class ModifyUserForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', ...)
```

To let a user modify his/her data, I'd like to set the value of the `password` input element to be empty:

```
...
if request.method=='GET':
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    modifyUserForm = ModifyUserForm(instance=user)
    modifyUserForm.fields['username'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
    modifyUserForm.fields['password'].widget.attrs['value'] = ''
```

Setting `username` input to `disabled` works; however, setting the `value` of `password` does not. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the `initial` form argument? `modifyUserForm = ModifyUserForm(instance=user, initial={'username':''})`?

Comment: Glad it helped. I've added it as an answer so that you can accept and close of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`initial` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#initial) on the form field:

```
modifyUserForm = ModifyUserForm(instance=user, initial={'username':''})
```